# How to find the basis of the Col($A$) from the basis of Null($A$)?

Tags: linear-algebra

In a linear algebra course, the textbook proves a version of the Dimension Theorem. More specifically, If $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix, then rank $A$ + dim Null($A$) = $n$.

The proof essentially says that if $B$ is the basis for $ \mathbb{R}^n$ and $B = \{{\vec v_1},...,{\vec v_n},{\vec v_{n+1}},...,{\vec v_k}\}$ and $\{{\vec v_1},...,{\vec v_n}\}$ is the basis for Null($A$), then $\{{\vec v_{n+1}},...,{\vec v_k}\}$ is the basis for Col($A$). Then it shows linear dependency for $\{{A\vec v_{n+1}},...,{A\vec v_k}\}$, and Span$\{{A\vec v_{n+1}},...,{A\vec v_k}\}$ = Col($A$) to complete the proof.

What I don't understand is that after the proof it says you can find the basis for Col($A$) from the basis for Null($A$) without example or explanation. What I think is the proof implies that since we have the basis for Null($A$), $B - \{{\vec v_{n+1}},...,{\vec v_k}\}$ gives us Col($A$), but it's unclear to me how to find $B$ and how that set subtraction works.

Comment: We have $\mathrm{Null}(A)\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathrm{Col}(A)\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m$, so there's no reason for a basis of the former to be related to a basis of the latter, as they live in very different places. The relation is just numeric, even if $m=n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick $\mathfrak B=\{v_1,\cdots,v_s\}$ a basis of $\operatorname{Null}A$. Complete $\mathfrak B$ to a basis $\mathfrak D=\{v_1,\cdots,v_s,w_1,\cdots,w_{n-s}\}$ of the whole $\Bbb R^n$. You should have learned a standard procedure to do it, for instance, pick any basis $\mathfrak C=\{c_1,\cdots,c_n\}$ of $\Bbb R^n$ and eliminate all the vectors $c_i$ such that $\operatorname{rk}(v_1,\cdots,v_s,c_i)\le s$. Perhaps not the smartest one, but without a doubt it is explicit, and it works in every field.

Then, $\{Aw_1,\cdots,Aw_{n-s}\}$ is a basis of $\operatorname{Col}A$. In fact, you know by rank-nullity theorem that $\dim\operatorname{Col}A=n-s$; those vectors are linearly independet because $$\alpha_1Aw_1+\cdots +\alpha_{n-s}Aw_{n-s}=A(\alpha_1w_1+\cdots+\alpha_{n-s}w_{n-s})=0\iff \\ \iff \alpha_1w_1+\cdots+\alpha_{n-s}w_{n-s}\in \operatorname{Null}A$$

And, by construction, the latter is true if ans only if $\alpha_1=\cdots=\alpha_{n-s}=0$.

Comment: Ahh that makes things very clear. Thanks a lot. What other procedures are there to complete $B$ to the basis of the whole $R^n$?

Answer (score 0):

$B$ is any basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$, meaning that the span of this basis is equal to all of $\mathbb{R}^n$. For example, in $\mathbb{R}^3$ the standard basis is $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$. Set difference is defined as $A-B=\{a | a\in A,a \notin B\}$. Given this information, does it clear up what you need to do?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense to me. I'm not sure if I am taught how to perform the set difference on sets of vectors (especially with different dimensions). Lets let the basis for Null($A$) is {(5,0,1),(0,2,1)}. What do I do next?

Comment: Depends on what you do. Your question was how to find $B$ and how set subtraction works. Could you perhaps elaborate on what you're trying to do?

Comment: Say a question provided me the basis of Null(A) is {(5,0,1),(0,2,1)}. How do I find Col(A) from this?

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly the book said that confused you? The part after the proof

Comment: It's unclear to me how to find $B$ and, it's unclear how set subtraction works for two sets of vectors with different dimensions. I guess I haven't learnt it yet, but I can't find anything online either

Comment: If you're just trying to find any $B$ that fits the criteria, then all you need to do is find an $n \times n$ invertable matrix and its columns will span $\mathbb{R}^n$. If you have a set $A = \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $B = \{2, 3, 5\}$, $A-B=\{0,1,4\}$